# subtract two DEMs and extract values that are greater than 1 and set zeros to null or no data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have two DEMs. my plan is to subtract 1 DEM from the other and extract only the values that are greater than 1 and set values that are less than 1 to no data or null

I can do this in 3 steps but I would like this to be done in 1 query in the raster calculator

```
1. dem2 - dem1 #output = subtract_DEM
2. subtract_DEM >= 1 #output = subtract_DEM_grt1
3. SetNull(0, subtract_DEM_grt1)
```

how can I compute this into one expression using the arcgis raster calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`Con`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm) function statement:

```
Con(('dem2'-'dem1')>=1,'dem2'-'dem1')
```

Check the result of subtraction of two DEMs:

[image]

Violet cell has a difference of 3; brown, 2; black, one; and whites spaces are `Null` values.